# Getting the data from SQL and inserting it inside the Java Textfield

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I've been trying to get the data from the SQL and insert it inside the JTextfield.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Management", "root", "admin"); 
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
String sql ="SELECT * FROM information WHERE id =?";

pst=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1,txtCustomerId.getText());
rs=pst.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()){
String ID = rs.getString("Firstname");
txtFirstname.setText(ID);
}
```

This code is in the button action, but when I clicked the button, there is nothing happening.

Comment: did you added a debug point at the if condition if (rs.next()) to see if the flow is going inside the if or not. Try that and update

Comment: if this code is at the button, try debugging if it is executed till the last line or getting any error before you reach the end of code also, try enclosing in try/catch block to get exception details if any.

Comment: this are the output, maybe my IDE has a problem? ---Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redo my JFrame and rewrite this code. There is no problem with this code. I think it just override because I copied the previous JFrame.